# RegEx To Match "whole word" returns exception

Tags: regex, vb.net, validation

I am trying to validate via RegEx as follows...

```
If Regex.IsMatch(Output, "\b" & "Serial)" & "\b") Then
'do something
end if
```

but i get this Argument exception

```
parsing "\bSerial)\b" - Too many )'s.
```

I do understand the error, but how should i modify the RegEx expression?

**UPDATE.** The word "Serial)" is generated dynamically. That means at least for me **i could get another exception** for another character too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paxdiablo and tanascius' answers correctly explain why your regex fails to compile.

*But:*

You need to be careful with your regex, even after escaping the parenthesis: `\b` only matches at **word boundaries** (a word being constructed from characters of the `\w` shortcut - letters, digits, and underscore), **not** after punctuation like parentheses. In your case the regex will not match in a string like `foo Serial) bar`. It *will* match in `foo Serial)bar`, but only because the `\b` matches *before* `bar`. Likewise, it won't match the string `Serial)`.

So, simply surrounding a string with `\b`s will not always do what you seem to be expecting it to do.

Edit: If, according to your comment below, in the following list...

```
foo Serial) bar
foo (Serial) bar
foo Serial). bar
foo Serial))))))
foo Serial)
```

...only the first and fifth should match, I'm inferring that the rule is to match a whole word only if it is preceded/followed by whitespace or start/end of string.

In that case, use

```
If Regex.IsMatch(Output, "(?<=^|\s)" & Regex.Escape("Serial)") & "(?=\s|$)") Then
```

However, this will now no longer match `foo` in `This is foo.` or `He said "foo"`. If you want to allow this, use

```
If Regex.IsMatch(Output, "(?<=^|\b|\s)" & Regex.Escape("Serial)") & "(?=\s|\b|$)") Then
```

...but this will now also match the second example. Choose your weapon carefully :)

(Explanation: `(?<=^|\b|\s)` is a positive lookbehind assertion that matches if it is possible to match either the start of the string, a word boundary, or a whitespace character right before the current position, without adding anything to the match result. `(?=\s|\b|$)` is its lookahead counterpart.)

Comment: I choose the first, and the fifth! Thanks Tim!

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that's VB.Net, you need to escape the `)`:

```
If Regex.IsMatch(Output, "\b" & "Serial\)" & "\b") Then
    'do something
End If
```

In .Net regular expressions, parentheses are the grouping characters.

---

If, as you say, the word 'Serial)' is generated dynamically, you will have to [escape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx) it before passing it to the RE engine:

```
If Regex.IsMatch(Output, "\b" & Regex.Escape("Serial)") & "\b") Then
    'do something
End If
```

---

As one other answerer has posted, this won't match `"Serial) xyz"` (for example) since there's no `\b` between the `)` and space (`\b` only exists *between* `\w` and `\W` characters and both `)` and a space are `\W`).

You may have to resort to an ugly hack like:

```
If Regex.IsMatch(Output, "\s" & Regex.Escape("Serial)") & "\s") _
Or Regex.IsMatch(Output, "\s" & Regex.Escape("Serial)") & "$") _
Or Regex.IsMatch(Output, "^" & Regex.Escape("Serial)") & "\s") _
Or Regex.IsMatch(Output, "^" & Regex.Escape("Serial)") & "$") _
Then
    'do something
End If
```

I thought that maybe you could match a character class consisting of (`^` or `$`) and `\s` along the lines of:

```
If Regex.IsMatch(Output, "[\s^]" & Regex.Escape("Serial)") & "[\s$]") Then
    'do something
End If
```

but this doesn't appear to work based on the regex tester [here](http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx) so you may have to go for the ugly hack version or you could combine them into a single regex as in:

```
var input = "Serial)"
var escaped = Regex.Escape (input)
var regex = "\s" & escaped & "\s|^" & escaped & "$|\s" & escaped & "$|^" & escaped & "\s"
If Regex.IsMatch(Output, regex) Then
    'do something
End If
```

Comment: For clarification, different flavors of regexp use grouping in different ways, posix regexp use `\\(` and `\\)` for grouping, perl regexps use simply `(` and `)` and uses `\\(` and `\\)` to mean the literal parentheses.

Comment: I guess i ll have to edit the question.
The word Serial) is generated dynamically

Comment: @strakastroukas, if it's an arbitrary string, the regular expression stuff has the ability to escape basic symbols - see the link in my update.

Comment: @Pax, if i use the Regex.Escape AND the Output contains "Serial)" the isMatch returns False

Comment: @paxdiablo: I think you meant for your update to have `Regex.Escape("Serial)")`, right?

Comment: @strakastroukas: oops, forgot to remove the backslash. Try that now.

Comment: @paxdiablo: Hello, and thanks once again, but i have the feeling that Tim Pietzcker has a good point.

Comment: Yes, he does indeed have a good point. I'm not sure how you'd solve it other than to use some hideous construct like `[\s$]` at the end instead of \b - and I'm not even sure that would work. I've updated the answer but you'll need to check it yourself. I don't have VS on the laptop I'm using - all my dev environment is at the office.

Comment: @strakastroukas: I have a solution (see final update) but it's a bit of a hack. Hopefully someone will come up with a better one for you.

Comment: @paxdiablo: I think we should have both take a break. The final update is not final because... it maches if the output contains "Serial " and the pattern to match is "Serial)"

Comment: Not according to that linked website. Are you sure you're using the escaped string to build the regex? What is the actual value of regex when constructed (should be `\sSerial\\)\s|^Serial\\)$|\sSerial\\)$|^Serial\\)\s`)?

Comment: I _will_ take a break however, since you've accepted another answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should escape your input by using [Regex.Escape()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx):

```
String input = "Serial)";
If Regex.IsMatch(Output, "\b" & Regex.Escape( input ) & "\b") Then
  'do something
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need may be

```
\bSerial\)\b
```

(that's  "\b" & "Serial)" & "\b"  )

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the brackets. that is, ) with )
So, the final string should look like, \bSerial)\b

If the content generates dynamically, search for "(" and ")" and replace them with appropriate escape character(just a string replacement!) to "(" and ")" or use Regex.Escape() to escape those characters!

HTH